# Cannot run Spring app because of lack of validator implementation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I see this error:

> The Bean Validation API is on the classpath but no implementation could be found

> Action:

> Add an implementation, such as Hibernate Validator, to the classpath

Every time i run my app.

This is how my dependencies look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to remove the following dependencies:

```
javax.validation:validation-api
org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator
jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api
```

The `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency already brings in all necessary implementations with the correct versions. At the moment you have conflicting versions having the old javax and the new jakarta validation dependencies.